# Easily create an animated glow

Tags: image, css, photoshop, image-editing

I created this image:
[image]

Using photoshop, but I had to make around 50 layers manually, and then create a gif out of it. Is there any easier way to automatically create an animated glow similar to this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use css animation.  Here is an example using a vanilla `div` container, but you can give it a background image:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  animation: glow 1s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes glow {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px -10px #aef4af;
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #aef4af;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Make sure you include Cross browser on animation / box-shadow, right now it will work only on Chrome.

Comment: @Cam Works for me without vendor prefixes on IE10+, Firefox, and Chrome.  http://caniuse.com lists `keyframes`, `animation`, and `box-shadow` support for these browsers as well.

Comment: I +1 your answer btw, but you should still include them for safe practice.